# Get identity of logged in Visual Studio user from extension

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-extensions, user-identification

I'm developing a visual studio 2015 extension and I'm looking to get the identity of the user who's logged into the IDE (different to the user logged in to windows, or running devenv).

I can't figure out where (or if) I can get that information. It doesn't appear to be in the [DTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx) object anywhere and googling around hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the username

```
string username = System.Environment.UserName;
```

or

```
string adName = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
```

Full UserPrinciple

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current
```

Most the normal .net methods for getting users from system or globals should work. All the AD namespaces (System.DirectoryServices) will also work as usual.

Also this regkey gets set at vs startup with the interactive user.
[image]

Comment: Couldn't that be different to the identity that the user logs in as in the IDE (the identity shown top-right)? i.e. I might be running devenv as one user, but actually log in to it as someone else.

Comment: You would have to test that. I do know that the active vs running user gets set to the reg key I added to the answer.

Comment: Actually are you looking for the "Live ID" instead of the computer user, the one shown in the top right of VS is the Microsoft Id, which may or may not have anything to do with the computer user.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry the question wasn't clear. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Looks like that reg. key is what I'm after. Will leave this open for a bit in case there's a type-safe way of accessing it, but otherwise I'll accept.

Comment: On my pc I could only find this registry information: -

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\ConnectedUser\IdeUserV2\Cache

I switch my Visual Studio 2019 login between two hotmail accounts and the data changed in this location.

Answer (score -2):

Code:
C#

> General: 
>   in header / above namespace 
>   MVC: Not sure about earlier version but 3 - 5 not required

`using System.Security.Principal`

> function, property etc

`string userid= User.Identity.Name.toString()`

Comment: That's for an MVC project. I'm talking about a visual studio extension.